NuGet. How to solve: The given key '(IBMMQDotnetClient, 9.4.1.0)' was not present in the dictionary?
.NET 8.0. Visual Studio 2022 v17.12.3.
I try to install the IBMMQDotnetClient NuGet package:
dotnet add package IBMMQDotnetClient --version 9.4.1

I get the error:

error: The given key '(IBMMQDotnetClient, 9.4.1.0)' was not present in
the dictionary.

How to solve the problem?

I don't get the error when I try the command myself.  Please provide a minimal repro: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
